# Openshift v2 connection closed by remote host while updating composer

Tags: git, composer-php, openshift

After pushing my commit to openshift, I usually get an error message and when it happens I log-in via ssh, delete the composer.lock file and rerun the composer install and update.
This time, while installing or updating the composer, I get the connection closed by remote host.
Any idea why?
Thanks